# How to make a recursive macro

Tags: tex-core, recursion

The following simple example is for typeseting `(a)(b)(c)(d)` by recursion. An error massage `ERROR: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{)}.` is received when running the code. What's wrong with it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\RecursiveTraversal[1]{(#1)\RecursiveTraversal}
\RecursiveTraversal{a}{b}{c}{d}\relax
\end{document}
```

Comment: you do not get that error you get `! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{)}.`

Comment: Sorry, I got wrong message. I have just update it. Thank you David Carlisle

Comment: you get that as eventually `#1` is `\end` (from `\end{document}` so you have `(\end)\RecursiveTraversal`  so `\end` gets your `)` as argument.

Comment: Why does `\relax` not work for it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This should have entered an infinite loop, shouldn't it?

Comment: @lyl  what would you expect relax to do???, you just do `(\relax)\RecursiveTraversal `  so it typesets () then loops again,

Comment: @Niranjan well it would except it stops on an error at `\end`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, so the next error they will have to face would be the one I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with defining a recursive macro but you have to program a way to break the recursion. I guess you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\RecursiveTraversal[1]{\ifx#1\relax\else(#1)\expandafter\RecursiveTraversal\fi}
\RecursiveTraversal{a}{b}{c}{d}\relax
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still dont't quite understand why a conditional judgement here must be added. What's the difference between `\expandafter...\fi` and just `\RecursiveTraversal`?

Comment: How is `\RecursiveTraversal` supposed to know when to stop the recursion? That's why the `\relax` is there at the end of the list. You could use any other macro, as long as it doesn't occur in you rlist.

Comment: @lyl without expandafter the call would be `\RecursiveTraversal\fi` so `#1` on the next call would be `\fi` not the next item in the list

Comment: Many thanks @campa@David Carlisle!! With your help and detail explanation I understand throughly the function of `\ifx` and `\relax` which are use to `terminate the recursion`.

Answer (score 6):

Note you should always look at the actual error message from TeX not some corrupted "summary" from your editor as TeX gives far more information.

The error is

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{)}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 \end
        {document}
?
```

Showing TeX had read `\end` (but not yet `{document}`) at the point it gave the error.

As campa showed, you have not terminated the recursion so eventually you had reached

`\RecursiveTraversal\end{document}`

so `#1` is `\end` so

`(\end)\RecursiveTraversal`

this typesets `(` then executes  `\end)` which is `\end{)}` and raises

`! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{)}.`